# Leetcode 3 longest substring (sliding window algorithm)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am working on the Leet Code challenge [3. Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/)

> #### 3. Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters
>
> Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

I've implemented a sliding algorithm solution. It passed most of the tests, however I cannot figure out why it won't pass a substring of "pwwkew".

What is wrong with my code?

```js
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {   
    let pointerA = 0;
    let pointerB = 0;
    let max = 0;
    
    let chars = [];
    
    while(pointerB < s.length) {
        if (!chars.includes(s[pointerB])) {
            chars.push(s[pointerB]);
            pointerB++;
            max = Math.max(chars.length, max);
        } else {
            chars = chars.filter(char => char !== s[pointerB]);
            pointerA = pointerA + 1;
        }
        
        console.log("pointerB: " + pointerB);
        console.log("pointerA: " + pointerA);
    }
    
    return max;
};

let result = lengthOfLongestSubstring("pwwkew");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What is your sliding algorithm supposed to do? What are the inputs and the expected outputs?

Comment: My knowledge of javascript is pretty limited but your window seems pretty inefficient - isn't `chars` an array, so performing a lookup of a character in your window possibly O(n) if the window is large? Also, after you remove the already seen character in your array, you need to catch pointerA up to pointerB; incrementing it isn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `else` block you are not excluding the characters that drop out of the window by increasing `pointerA`. Moreover, you cannot just apply `filter`, as that will break gaps in the "window". Instead you should locate where the duplicate character is sitting, and move `pointerA` beyond that point, while removing as many characters from `chars`:

```js
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {   
  let pointerA = 0;
  let pointerB = 0;
  let max = 0;

  let chars = [];

  while(pointerB < s.length) {
      if (!chars.includes(s[pointerB])) {
          chars.push(s[pointerB]);
          pointerB++;
          max = Math.max(chars.length, max);
      } else {
          pointerA = chars.indexOf(s[pointerB]) + 1;
          chars = chars.slice(pointerA);
      }
  }

  return max;
};

let res = lengthOfLongestSubstring("pwwkew");
console.log(res);
```

Note that this algorithm is not optimal: finding where the duplicate character is sitting needs a scan over potentially many characters. It is better to maintain a `Map` of where each character was found.

Here is the code I submitted:

```
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {
    const map = new Map;
    let longest = 0, start = 0, ch, pos;
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        ch = s[i];
        pos = map.get(ch);
        if (pos) {
            if (i - start > longest) longest = i - start;
            while (start < pos) map.set(s[start++], 0);
        }
        map.set(ch, i+1);
    }
    return Math.max(longest, s.length - start);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
public:
    int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
        int* a = new int[257];
        int ans = 0;
        int n = s.size();
        for (int j = 0, i = 0; j < n; j++) {
            i = i > a[s[j]] ? i : a[s[j]];
            ans = ans > j - i +1 ? ans : j - i + 1;
            a[s[j]] = j + 1;
        }
        return ans;
     }
 };
```

Try this code using C++ format at Leetcode you will passed..